# Can conda channels include multiple channels?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm reading the [documentation on Conda channels](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/channels.html), and the documentation appears to state that:

- By default, Conda uses the `defaults` channel. This can be verified locally:

```
% conda config --show channels
channels:
  - defaults
```

- The `defaults` channel is hosted on [repo.anaconda.com](https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs)

However, a quick glance at the landing page shows that this channel seems to include multiple channels, such as `pkgs/main`, `pkgs/free`, etc. This is extra confusing because this reflects the output of a similar command to list default channels:

```
% conda config --show default_channels
default_channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
```

So my question is, what exactly is a channel? Is `defaults` just a special, hard-coded alias for a list of default channels, namely `pkgs/main` and `pkgs/r`? Or can any channel declare that it includes multiple channels within itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.condarc` file there are several keys of interest: `channels`, `custom_multichannels`, `default_channels`, and `channel_alias`

Any values listed under `channels` are a single channel or a multi-channel that conda will search.  A single channel such as `conda-forge` can be listed using just the channel name or the url.

```
channels:
  - https://my.customrepo.org/dev/win-64
  - conda-forge
```

But you can also define multi-channels, which are just a collection of channels with a name, and then reference that.  In the example below, the `internal-dev` is not a channel on http://conda.anaconda.org, but instead is the name of a multichannel pointing to a set of internal channels.

```
channels:
  - conda-forge

custom_multichannels:
  internal-dev:
    - https://conda.mywork.site/dev/noarch
    - https://conda.mywork.site/dev/win-64
```

Now, you can refer to the `interanl-dev` channel when using conda:

```
conda create -n testenv python some_dev_package -c internal-dev
```

You can also reference it in your list of default channels in the `.condarc` file.

```
channels:
  - internal-dev
  - conda-forge

custom_multichannels:
  internal-dev:
    - https://conda.mywork.site/dev/noarch
    - https://conda.mywork.site/dev/win-64
```

The `default_channels` key is just another multichannel, with a pre-defined name of `defaults`.  The following two .condarc YAML files are functionally equivalent:

```
channels:
  - internal-dev
  - defaults
  - fastai

default_channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r

custom_multichannels:
  internal-dev:
    - https://conda.mywork.site/dev/noarch
    - https://conda.mywork.site/dev/win-64
```

```
channels:
  - internal-dev
  - defaults
  - fastai

custom_multichannels:
  defaults:
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
  internal-dev:
    - https://conda.mywork.site/dev/noarch
    - https://conda.mywork.site/dev/win-64
```

The last key to be aware of is `channel_alias`.  This sets the default server to use as the root for finding channels.  The default is `https://conda.anaconda.org`.  However, if you have an internal conda server that you use almost exclusively, you can change this value so you can reference the channels by just their name.

```
channel_alias: https://conda.mywork.site

channels:
  - internal-dev
  - defaults
  - fastai

default_channels:
  - anaconda
  - r

custom_multichannels:
  internal-dev:
    - dev-build
    - dev-test
```

All of the above channels point to `https://conda.mywork.site/<channel>` and not to an outside server.  To point to a channel on the internet, you would need to use the full URL (i.e. `https://conda.anacond.org/conda-forge`)